# How to find the time of a particular line of code added in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Day1 I add some code.
And next Day 2 I add some more lines of code in the previous code.
and now if I am watching my code on Day 3, how can I trace that this particular line of code was added on day 2.

Answer (score 4):

For recent changes you can right click on the file and choose 'Compare With... > Local History...'.

Eclipse will show you a list of the change history it has with the date and time that the file was saved, double clicking on an entry in the list will show you the differences between the current version and the historic entry.

How long Eclipse keeps the local history is configured in the Preferences on the 'General > Workspace > Local History' page.

For more long term history you need to use a source control system such as SVN or GIT.

Comment: thanks for replying. I have already checked that. Was just thinking if there is some shorter way to find just one line because when the code is huge, it becomes a mess to search.